# Recursive Function -trying to understand

Tags: c#, function, recursion

I have problems with this code. It isn't work or homework. I'm only trying to understand the recursive function.  The code was working at first,  but when it found a word with more than 22000 characters, it caused the throwing of an error - a stackoverflowexception.

This is the code

```
using System;

namespace Palindrome
{
    using System.IO;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int c = 0;

            string[] l = File.ReadAllLines("UKACD17.TXT");
            for (int i = 0; i < l.Length; i++)
            {
                string ll = l[i];
                if (T(ll))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ll);
                    c++;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Found {0} palindromes.", c);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static bool T(string s)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) return false;
            return s.Length == 1 || (s[0] == s[s.Length - 1] && T(s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2)));
        }
    }}
```

Comment: The size of the stack is finite.

Comment: You can trivially formulate much more efficient both recursive and non-recursive solutions, but I guess that's not what the question is about - efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method looks logically correct, but it won't work because of practical limitations on the computer executing your code.

Whenever you invoke a method, it pushes the calling method's state onto a stack - basically a block of memory containing the data which will allow execution to continue in the calling method once the called method has executed.

This block of memory is non-trivially sized, so if you are trying to invoke the method recursively 11000 times (for a 22000 char initial input), that would require 11000 stack frames to be pushed - and this is evidently a way deeper recursion than is allowed (and it probably gives up long before 11000 too).

The limit is set, I imagine, since you would otherwise use up limited memory which could be used for other, more useful, things.

Instead of invoking the method recursively, you can turn it into a loop:

```
private static boolean T(string s) {
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) return false;
  int i = 0;
  int j = s.length - 1;
  while (i < j) {
    if (s[i] != s[j]) return false;
    i++; j--;
  }
  return true;
}
```

This uses two pointers into the string which you move towards each other - at each step, if they point to different characters, it can't be a palindrome, so you can return false; otherwise, move them towards each other and repeat.

This is far cheaper to invoke because there is no need to push a stack frame - all you are doing is comparing characters and incrementing/decrementing a couple of integers.